# The orthography of gi and ci

Tags: pronunciation, orthography

I was reading about where to place Italian stress and how to pronounce *ci* & *gi*. On this site

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Italian_orthography#C_and_G

there's a paragraph that says the following: in *camicia* the first *i* is stressed thus -cia is pronounced /tʃa/. That is confusing me because the stress is not on the final a so applying what I just read I thought *i* in *ci* should be stressed & that is incorrect... put another way the second to last syllables stressed and no other vowels are therefore *ci* is /tʃ/.

As for this other example *farmacia* there is no grave marker on the final a and I just suppose the stress is on the second to last syllable which means the second a would be stressed - however if none of the other vowels are supposed to be stressed except for one then why does the *i* get pronounced as /i/?

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Comment: Notice that in both words the stress is on the second to last syllable. In the first case it's _-mi-_ (and the whole word has 3 syllables), while in the second case it's _-ci-_ (and the whole word has 4 syllables).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Italian there are no hard and fast rules about stress. Even native speakers sometimes (often?) get it wrong on unfamiliar words. The only way to find the correct position of the stress of any given word is to consult a dictionary. Let's do it together for the words that confuse you. I will use the *Vocabolario Treccani*, as it is free online and quite good.

In the case of *camicia* the Vocabolario [gives us](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/camicia/) *camìcia*. This indicates that the stress is on the second syllable, in particular the digraph *cia* (which carries no stress) represents the sound /tʃa/. On the whole the complete pronunciation of the word is /ka'mitʃa/.

In the case of *farmacia* the Vocabolario [gives us](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/farmacia/) *farmacìa*. Note that now the stress is on the *i*: this implies that the digraph *ci* is not pronounced as the single consonant /tʃ/, but as the syllable /tʃi/. On the whole the pronunciation is /farma'tʃia/.

Answer (score 4):

The letter “i” has a dual usage in Italian orthography. It can represent the vowel /i/ (*filo* or *idea*) or the consonant /j/ (*ieri* or *febbraio*), but it can also a pure orthographic device to indicate the pronunciation of a preceding *c* or *g* letter as /tʃ/ or /dʒ/.

<sup>The consonant /j/ is always represented by *i* in current Italian, so we could well say the letter has a three-pronged usage. In the past one could find *j* representing /j/, the usage only survives in some toponyms or surnames and a few reimported latinisms such as *junior* and similar.</sup>

In the second case it is not pronounced at all. For instance

*anca* is pronounced /'an.ka/ (hip)
*ancia* is pronounced /'an.tʃa/ (reed)

However, this poses some problems because the tonic accent position is not generally marked in Italian orthography. A *non* minimal pair that could be tough for beginners is

*maga* /'ma.ga/ (sorceress)
*magia* /ma.'dʒi.a/ (magic, enchantment)

The second word has three syllables and the tonic accent is on the vowel [i]. How do I know? Because I know Italian! There's no hint from the orthography that can help to guess the right pronunciation.

Even the plural form doesn't help! The plural of *camicia* is spelled *camicie*, just like the plural of *farmacia* is *farmacie*. But *camicie* has three syllables, and *farmacie* still is four syllables /far.ma.'tʃi.e/.

In other cases it can help, because the plural of *maga* is *maghe* (the *h* keeps the /g/ pronunciation) and the plural of *magia* is *magie*.

One might say that in *farmacia* and *magia* the *i* has both functions active: vowel marker *and* “softener marker” for *c* or *g*. Unfortunately, the orthographic conventions of Italian don't help in correctly placing the tonic accent.

Only the dictionary can help, I'm afraid. Other examples:

*bigia* /'bi.dʒa/ (ash grey [feminine adjective])
*bugia* /bu.'dʒi.a/ (lie)

*Belgio* /'bel.dʒo/ (Belgium)
*nostalgia* /nos.tal.'dʒi.a/ (nostalgia, homesickness)

*vocio* /vo.'tʃi.o/ (clamour), with plural *vocii* (yes, with two *i*’s)

*regia* /'re.dʒa/ (royal [feminine adjective])
*regia* /re.'dʒi.a/ (direction [films or stage])

The last two words are written the same way, but pronounced very differently (thanks to DaG for mentioning them). There is also the pair of names

*Lucio* /'lu.tʃo/ [masculine]
*Lucia* /lu.'tʃi.a/ [feminine]

Both names come from Latin *lux*, but for some reasons the accent has been moved in the feminine version.

Comment: There are even rare cases where the same spelling denotes two different words with different pronunciation and meaning. For instance, _regia_: when pronounced /re.'dʒi.a/ it means “direction” (of plays and films), while /'rɛ.dʒa/ is the feminine form of _regio_, “royal”.

Comment: @DaG Thanks for the addition! I'll add it.

Comment: "*The consonant /j/ is always represented by i in Italian*". I would not say "*always*"; there are exceptions, in particular when the semi-consonant sound is at the beginning of the word, as in "mar Jonio" (but "mar Ionio" is correct too), or the word is a latinism, as in "campionato juniores" or "Juventus" (in wich cases the "j" should not be replaced by an "i").

Comment: @secan These are rare exceptions. I'll add some words.

Comment: @egreg, sure, I was not implying they are widespread; my intent was just to point out there are few exceptions, for the sake of completeness. ;)

Comment: @secan And no school teacher will ever admit that *i* can be a consonant! ;-)

Comment: Well, mine thought me that an "i" between to vowels or at the beginning of a word and followed by a vowel has the value of *semi-* consonant, so there is at least one... well, at least there *was*; she was already ancient when I was a kid so I cannot guarantee she's still among us. XD

Answer (score -2):

In Italian, if the i in ci is stressed, then it is pronounced. If the stress falls somewhere else in the word, then it is silent. The problem is, Italian doesn't tell you where the stress is unless it is on the last syllable (città).

However, if you know Spanish, you can use that language as a guide, because every word in Spanish has stress marked according to certain rules.

For example, camicia in Italian is related to the Spanish word camisa. The "i" next to the letter "m" is stressed in the Spanish word because if a word has no accent and ends in a vowel, n, or s, the second-last syllable is stressed (not always the same in Italian). Therefore, the "i" next to the letter "m" in camicia is stressed, and that means the second i is silent.

This rule also allows you to spot connections between certain suffixes and stress. For example, if I were to learn Italian, I would already know that the suffix ologo causes antepenultimate stress (biologo, geologo), because in Spanish it is written ólogo.

Unfortunately, it doesn't work for farmacia because in Spanish it is stressed on the second a whereas in Italian, it is stressed on the i. However, it will guide you well most of the time.

Comment: Not only this answer is not an answer, not only it elaborates on Spanish in a site about Italian, but some of what it says is also plain wrong. It's false that in Spanish “if a word has no accent, the second syllable is stressed”. If anything, the last but one is stressed, and even that is only true if it terminates by vowel, “s” or “n”. Am I correct, @Charo?

Comment: Yes, I simplified it too much. I'll fix it. However, I'm just saying that learners of Italian who also speak Spanish will find it useful putting their Spanish knowledge to work rather than having to look up every antepenultimate stressed word in the dictionary. Am I not correct in that this trick usually works? Why does it not answer the question?