# Are the pronunciations of "cie", "ce", "gie", "ge" the same when the letter "i" is used to soften?

Tags: vocabulary, pronunciation, sound

Are the pronunciations of "cie", "ce", "gie", "ge" the same when the letter "i" is used to soften?
Why I'm asking it is because I saw some words as you can see below;

1. Cielo = It is pronounced as if there is no *i* sound there. It sounds like "celo"
2. Astrologie = It is pronounced with the sound of the letter "i".

I have been taught that if the letter "i" comes after "g" or "c", it makes their sounds soft and it doesn't get pronounced.
My questions are:

1-) If this rule is correct, why is there "i" sound in the word "astrologie" ?

2-) Why does the word "cielo" sound like "celo" ? Are "cie" and "ce" the same?

3-) Is there any Italian words including "cie" that has the sound of the letter "i" during its pronunciation like "astrolo*gie*" ?

Comment: Related question: https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/13416/.

Answer (score 5):

If the *i* is unstressed (as in *cielo*), *cie*/*ce* and *gie*/*ge* are pronounced the same. If it is stressed, though (as in *astrologia*, *astrologie* and likewise e.g. *farmacia*, *farmacie*), it is pronounced even before an *e*.

Comment: Is this situation special for the letters with soft and strong sounds? Are there any words including "bie", "die", "vie", "lie" in which the letter "i" doesn't get pronounced? I think there aren't. If there is the letter "i" with a vowel that has just one sound possible, then "i" must be pronounced, right?

Comment: @Jawel7: As the answer clearly explains, in _cie_ and _gie_ (and _cia_ and _gia_ etc.), if the _i_ is unstressed, “ci” or “gi” may be considered a single grapheme, say the equivalent of (I think) “č” or “ch” in other languages. After any other consonant, the “i” is an actual letter, with different sounds whether stressed (“fobie”, “ferrovie”, “malie”...) or unstressed (“guardie”, “veliero”, “cavie”...). In the first case, it is the normal vowel /i/, in the second one it is the semivowel /j/.